# AVPlayer not supporting external webVtt file subtitle in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

> I am using swift 3 and trying to add subtitle using webVtt file but it is not working and crashing my app. see my code below.

```
 let asset1 = AVAsset(url: URL(string: playUrl)! // HLS video link

   //Create AVMutableComposition
    let videoPlusSubtitles = AVMutableComposition()

    //Adds video track
    let videoTrack = videoPlusSubtitles.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    try? videoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset1.duration),
                                     of: asset1.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0],
                                     at: kCMTimeZero)

    //Adds subtitle track
    let subtitleAsset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: SubtittleUrl)!)
    print("Subtitle CC: \(SubtittleUrl)")

    let subtitleTrack = videoPlusSubtitles.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .text, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    try? subtitleTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset1.duration),
                                        of: subtitleAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .text)[0],
                                        at: kCMTimeZero)
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: videoPlusSubtitles)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    playerLayer?.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer!, at: 0)
    player?.play()
```

> please suggest me solution that how can I display subtitles on my videos using external subtitle files using vtt or srt extensions.

Comment: can you share the subtitle url, you are feeding the avplayer?

Comment: it's secure url and hosted on AWS so that url will not work in external environment.

Comment: Can you share the crash log then?